# Sql error with query #1064

Tags: sql

Hi i am trying to run a query on a database, but i keep getting this error, do you see anything wrong with my query?

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' and not in (SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE 'beauty%')
```

thanx

Comment: ...and `Category` NOT IN (SELE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this area:

> and not in

The corect syntax is

```
and not <field name> in (Select <INDIVIDUAL FIELD> from ...)
```

You can't do a subquery in a where clause where you are selecting all coumns  (*)  You need to select one individual column in the subquery and tie it to one column in your main query.

So the full statement should be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' and `Category` not in (SELECT Category
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE 'beauty%')
```

It's equivalent to

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' and `Category`  NOT LIKE 'beauty%'
```

which is a lot more readable IMO

For more info on using subqueries in an IN statement in a WHERE clause, see http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

Scroll down to find "Correlated Subquery" in the article.

Comment: "and `Category` NOT `Category` LIKE 'beauty%'" should be "and `Category` NOT LIKE 'beauty%'"

Comment: Thnx. That would have been helpful before in stupidly truncated the table :) Oh well i have the dump at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' and `Category` not in 
    (SELECT `Category`
     FROM `data`
     WHERE `Category` LIKE 'beauty%')
```

Comment: This will only work if "data" contains only one column.  Even then most tools will balk at using * in a subquery in a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query should look like this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `data`
WHERE    `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' 
AND      `Category` NOT IN
(
    SELECT   `Category`
    FROM     `data`
    WHERE    `Category` LIKE 'beauty%'
)
```

Anyway, I would rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `data`
WHERE    `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' 
AND      `Category` NOT LIKE 'beauty%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' 
and `Category` not in (SELECT *
                      FROM `data` 
                      WHERE `Category` LIKE 'beauty%')
```

Answer (score 0):

... and `Category` ?

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' and `Category` not in (SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE 'beauty%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a subquery here? This should be your query

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`
WHERE `Category` LIKE '%beauty%' and `Category` not LIKE 'beauty%'
```